# How to remove plus button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting input fields with values from database. See below code:

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium" name="demoname" id="demo_1" value="txt1"/>
<button type="button" class="btn id="plus_1"><span class="icon" id="add1">Plus</span> </button>
<input type="text" class="input-medium" name="demoname" id="demo_2" value="txt2"/>
<button type="button" class="btn id="plus_2"><span class="icon " id="add2">Plus</span></button>
<input type="text" class="input-medium" name="demoname" id="demo_3" value="txt3"/>
<button type="button" class="btn id="plus_3"><span class="icon " id="add3">Plus</span></button>
```

Now, I need the first plus button to show whenever a page opens. I want the rest of the plus buttons to hide.

The input am getting form database will be n number. So, whenever any new data comes from database also it has to show only first plus button.Other buttons has to hide.

The input fields are dynamically created.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `"` to close the class of your buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="plus_1">
// ---------------------------  ^ here
```

then you can apply CSS to hide all of your button with class `btn` by default:

```
.btn {
    display: none;
}
```

then use **[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)** to show the first button:

```
$('.btn').first().show();
```

or **[:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** selector:

```
$('.btn:first').show();
```

If you prefer pure jQuery solution, you can use:

```
$('.btn').hide().first().show();
```

If you want to use pure CSS approach, then:

```
.btn:not(:first-of-type) { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: I used all your codes. However, its not working ..Since am having a lot of btn class in that page..I used another class to implement it.When i use dsplay:none its working. But, when i apply jquery its not working.I applied on document.ready func() also but not works..

Answer (score 0):

Use css

```
.btn {
    display: none;
}
.btn:first-of-type {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kyCL/

Comment: Or just `.btn:not(:first-of-type) { display: none; }`.

Comment: Even better, null's version won't clash with any `block` or `inline-block` you wish to apply to the button.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to close off the class quote. And i've created a div with and ID to place these within.

Here you go, with html and script

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="buttonArea">
<input type="text" class="input-medium" name="demoname" id="demo_1" value="txt1"/>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="plus_1"><span class="icon" id="add1">Plus</span> </button>
<input type="text" class="input-medium" name="demoname" id="demo_2" value="txt2"/>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="plus_2"><span class="icon " id="add2">Plus</span></button>
<input type="text" class="input-medium" name="demoname" id="demo_3" value="txt3"/>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="plus_3"><span class="icon " id="add3">Plus</span></button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#buttonArea button:not(:first)').hide()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```